# Where should a thunk come, if it does not alter client storage?

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

There is a thunk which does not store any locally, on client side. It sends a message to backend, and then navigates to an other page.

I guess it is a good practice not let axios call in component, but to which slice I should store it?

Shall I have a slice only for this endpoint call? And store "only" wheter request was sent / response received?